# Volume is rendering through objects in foreground

Tags: rendering, node-editor, compositing-nodes, volumetrics

I'm trying to recreate the planet with the asteroid belt from [the force awakens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THUES.jpg),

[image]

but my renders come up like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuL0N.jpg).

[image]

[image]

Atmosphere and without respectively. You can see the asteroid belt that is behind the planet, and the asteroid belt messes with the atmosphere. does anyone know how to fix this?

[Here's the blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i1khcy79ryzq4n5/voulmetrics%20help.blend?dl=0)

Answer (score 1):

The belt geometry is criss-crossing itself (exaggerated here for demonstration purposes):

[image]

To fix, delete and one side and re-extrude, this time being sure that it does not self-intersect.

1. <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> into edit mode, <kbd>⌦ Delete</kbd>
2. <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude, then drag the mouse around. If the extrusion does not already appear to be locked along the object's local Z axis (there should be a line indicating this), press <kbd>Z</kbd> twice. Then press `1` to extrude exactly one blender unit (or whatever value you desire), precisely along the blue line.

Another alternative is to use the [solidify modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/solidify.html).

[image]

[image]

---

Also note that your clipping settings are causing lots of artifacts in the viewport. Generally you want to keep the clipping range as small as you can. I found `.1` . . . `1000` to work fairly well in this scene.

Comment: I fully replaced the circle with a torus and gave it a volume scatter/absorbtion shader and the volume still goes through the foreground. I don't know what to do now. I just gave the torus a transparent shader and it does the strange shadow thing over the top of the planet seen in my second image

Comment: @elmo274 Make sure the normals are facing in the right direction. Apply the scale (Ctrl A), then switch to edit mode, select all, and press Ctrl N.

Comment: That did help with the strange shadow thing seen in pic 2. But you can still see the ring through the planet. I fixed it since I just deleted the geometry behind the planet and aligned the edges with the edges of the planet.

Comment: @elmo274 Hm.. I uploaded a version of .blend where the ring is occluded correctly, at least for me. Does it work on your end?